# Is map $\alpha: R \times R \rightarrow R$ where $\alpha(r,s) = rs$ a ring homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to figure out if the map $\alpha: R \times R \rightarrow R$ where $\alpha(r,s) = rs$ is a ring homomorphism.

I know that $\alpha: R \times R \rightarrow R$ where $\alpha(r,s) = r + s$ is not a ring homomorphism because $\alpha[(r,s)\cdot (r^{'}, s^{'})] = rr^{'} + ss^{'}$ but doesn't equal $(r+s)(r^{'}+s^{'}) = \alpha(r,s)\alpha(r^{'},s^{'})$.

I can't figure out how the addition and multiplication tests I'm supposed to be using to test $\alpha(r,s) = rs$ for a homormorphism work as with the example above.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to test whether $\alpha[(r,s)\cdot(r',s')] = \alpha(r,s)\alpha(r',s')$. Is $R$ a commutative ring? (PS: in TeX just use `'`, not `^'`—the superscript is built into the definition of `'`.)

Comment: $R$ is any commutative ring, or specifically $\mathbb R?$

Comment: Is $$\alpha\left((r_1,s_1)+(r_2,s_2)\right)=\alpha(r_1,s_1)+\alpha(r_2,s_2)?$$

Comment: R is simply specified as "a ring."

Comment: No it isn't, if you discard $rs = 0$ as a possible multiplication